# Problem with finding Excel rows using Python based on 1 condition

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

I am trying to to find all the rows in excel that contain earlier dates than 2016-09-24, and save them as `to_delete`, however, when I run the given code it simply gives me row 1, which is my header row. Any advice on how I could fix this (I do not want to erase my header row)?

```
import datetime as dt

for day in ws.range('L2:L{}'.format(last_row)):
    if day.value <= dt.datetime(2016, 9, 24, 0, 0): # checks if day is not prior to the change of the rules
        to_delete = int(day.get_address(0, 0)[1:])-1 # the actual row is the one before the rule change, hence minus 1
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new df that is a subset of your original df.

```
date = '2016-09-24'
to_delete = df.loc[df['Day'] < pd.to_datetime(date)]
```